# Java Multi-thread networking, Good or bad?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I run multiple game servers and I want to develop a custom application to manage them. Basically all the game servers will connect to the application to exchange data. I don't want any of this data getting lost so I think it would be best to use TCP. I have looked into networking and understand how it works however I have a question about cpu usage. More servers are being added and in the next few months it could potentially reach around 100 - 200 and will continue to grow as needed. Will new threads for each server use a lot of cpu and is it a good idea to do this? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: A bit broad here. well, just try it. Multi-thread networkiing is good stuff.

Comment: 100s of threads should perform well as long as you have a decent amount of memory on your box and a reasonably recent *nix kernel.  We run with a ton more threads than that.

Comment: Thread-per-socket is not a scalable model, no.  CPUs are significantly faster than networks, one thread can keep up with many client-computers.

Comment: One-thread-per-connection is good for simplicity, when you have only a few connections. It might still work for 100-200 but that's getting into the range where you'll need to switch to nonblocking IO for performance.

Comment: It's less about the number of threads @Affe and more about code complexity and maintenance IMO.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at non blocking io. With blocking io, each socket will consume 1 thread and the number of threads in a system is limited. And even if you can create 1000+, it is a questionable approach.

With non blocking io, you can server multiple sockets with a single thread. This is a more scalable approach + you control how many threads at any given moment are running.

Comment: Creating many threads will also cost a lot of memory, because each thread has a stack (with a default size of 2 MB, on Windows with Oracle Java). So, for example 1000 threads = 2 GB of memory just for the stacks of all those threads.

Answer (score 0):

> More servers are being added and in the next few months it could potentially reach around 100 - 200 and will continue to grow as needed. Will new threads for each server use a lot of cpu and is it a good idea to do this?

It is a standard answer to caution away from 100s of threads and to the NIO solution.  However, it is important to note that the NIO approach has a significantly more complex implementation.  Isolating the interaction with a server connection to a single thread has its advantages from a code standpoint.

Modern OS' can fork 1000s of threads with little overhead aside from the stack memory.  If you are sure of your scaling factors (i.e. you're not going to reach 10k connections or something) and you have the core memory then I would say that a thread per TCP connection could work very well.  I've very successfully run applications with 1000s of threads and have not seen fall offs in performance due to context switching which used to be the case with earlier processors/kernels.